# replacing main drive in a multi-OS setup without breaking GRUB or reinstalling every OS

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, grub, disk-cloning

I have two NVMe drives on my PC, the first (and original) one has Windows, the default OS on my PC.

Later on, I added a second NVMe drive, where I installed a few Linux distributions.

I get a menu at boot that lets me select the OS, I set it up using GRUB, if I remember correctly.
If I am not mistaken, the boot menu may be stored on the second drive.

I would like to upgrade the first drive from a 1TB to a faster 2TB NVMe.
Is it possible to replace it without breaking anything or being forced to reinstall everything?

Would cloning the 1TB into the new 2TB via a laptop work?

Comment: A perfect clone should work (I would suggest `dd` in Ubuntu Live). Once you have cloned and logged back into Windows, it should be able to expand. However, if there are any partitions after the Windows partition, then you will need to expand it using a tool such a gparted to move those partitions to the end of the drive before expanding Windows. Also, this assumes you aren't using bitlocker.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I am not too concerned about the extra partitions on Drive 1, I can even delete them after backup and then restore them. They only contain user data. Windows also allows resizing partitions easily.

So the GRUB boot menu will not get messed up? It's not linked to the model of the NVMe?

Comment: The extra partitions I worry about are the hidden one that Windows needs to boot.

Comment: It should not mess up grub as long as you are creating a perfect clone

Comment: Theoretically, I could also live with an identical C partition (134GB free right now) and only resize the D and E partitions with the extra 1TB I'd get.

In that case, just cloning is probably fine and I wouldn't need gparted? According to Windows, I have 2 hidden partitions before C, one Recovery and one EFI, followed by D and E that I use for data, so if I clone, the unallocated space should be at the end of the drive and can be allocated to D and E via Windows Computer Management tool, correct?

Comment: I believe you are right

Comment: cool, thank you very much, you've been a big help!